# ring: specifying a port (80 for production)

Tags: clojure, port, ring

Based on some apprentice-level googling I've found that in project.clj

```
  :ring {:handler pach.handler/app
         :port 4004}
```

Will work fine, but trying to set the default port to 80 does not seem to play nicely.

How would I set this value for a production server?

Comment: You can't open ports under 1024 without being root. Perhaps that's your issue? See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user) for info about that.

Comment: Yep!  You nailed it.  Thanks :D